# question about PN junction bias and currents in long\short diodes

Tags: pn-junction

I am trying to understand which current is bigger under forward bias.
The current in a short diode or in a long diode?
(with the same concentrations)

What I know is this:
[image: currents in long and short diode:]
[image: concentrations on each side of the junction:]

So I understand how the current expressions are derived, but I cant seem to get which will be bigger under the same conditions?

In a short diode:

$$W_{p}^1=w_{p} - x_{p}$$
$$W_{n}^1=w_{n} - x_{n}$$

How do I calculate $$w_{p}$$ and $$x_{p}$$?
In this case, is in fact $$L_{p}=x_{p}$$? appreciate the help

Comment: This is new to me, what is a short diode and what is a long diode? Are you referring to the packaging or the die?

Comment: I mean the base of the diode. Short or long base.

Comment: I am still confused what is the base of the diode, are you referring to the package?

Comment: *L* marked in the attached figure seems to be the characteristic length of diffusion. *w* seems to be the physical distance from junction to the contact. For long diode, the injected carriers (who, after crossing the junction are now minority carriers) get recombined before reaching the external terminal/contact of the diode. @Gil